# Is a Scythe an official weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, equipment

The sickle is an in-game weapon, but I couldn't find the stats for the Scythe.
I remember in 3.5 it had a Scythe.
In the DM book, I found that Avatar of Death use a Scythe with the following stats

> **Scythe**
>
> Damage: 1d8

I want to know if there is an official War Scythe in D&D 5e and where I could find it.
If not, what would be the stats for it?

Comment: What is your reference for the war scythe?  A different game? (I recall that in the Diablo II crpg there was a war scythe weapon/pole arm).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Scythes do not have a stat block in 5th Edition D&D

Whether you're a DM looking to issue a Scythe to a player, or a player trying to convince your DM to permit your character to use one, you'll need to roll your own statblock for it; there's neither a Mundane nor Magical Scythe to draw from.

### My recommendation is to use the statblock for a Glaive or Halbard (which are the same)

The reasons for this are that it's most likely to give you a weapon that resembles the classical manner in which a Scythe is used* in combat:

- It will gain the *Two-Handed* property, matching the expectation that the weapon will be larger and wielded with two hands
- It will gain the *Reach* property, which lets the user fight from a significant distance
- It will gain the *Heavy* property, a companion property to the *Two-Handed* property that for many weapons will make them unwieldy for smaller characters

I would probably disallow gaining benefits from the *Polearm Master* feat though, since a *Scythe* is pretty unlikely to function the exact same as a Polearm, in terms of how it is swung.

<sup>* In Fantasy Fiction. In real life, Scythes are notoriously difficult and unfit to be used as weapons, and if D&D were attempting to recreate real life combat 1-to-1, Scythes would probably have a very poor statblock to capture that issue.</sup>

Comment: I'd be hesitant to allow it the reach property for much the same reason you've mentioned. Polearm weapons can be used for reach since you are jabbing with them but scythes just don't work like that.

Comment: @AllanMills Depends on what we're talking about. Fantasy Fiction (which is the only realm in which using a *Scythe* as a weapon makes remote sense) trends towards long "polearm-like" weapons with a curved blade, the entirety of which would extend way beyond the wielder's total height. Giving it the *Reach* property isn't ridiculous in that context.

Comment: +1 for your footnote - scythes are fundamentally terrible weapons, despite what fantasy media seems to want us to think.

Comment: It may be worth adding to your footnote that when peasants were forced to fight and use their own farm implements to do it—the only time someone would use a scythe in combat—they would usually try to modify the scythe so that the blade pointed straight instead of at a right angle, making it more of a cheap/shoddy glaive or spear than a scythe.

Comment: Agricultural scythes are definitely terrible weapons but the question does mention the "[war scythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_scythe)", specifically - a polearm with the cutting edge on the inside of the curve which would seem to be quite fairly described using the stats for the glaive/halberd.

Comment: Fighting with the farmer scythe is indeed weird but their are actual medieval manuscripts describing how to use it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paulus_Hector_Mair
The War scythe is a scythe with the bent in the attachment between pole and blade beaten straight which is generally seen as one of the precursors for the glaive.

Comment: [War scythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_scythe) looks really similar to [polearm](https://www.celticwebmerchant.com/en/pudao-chinese-polearm.html), so why would it function differently? I see no reason to disable Polearm Master on it. Of course regular field scythe should rather be improvised weapon - as you correctly state in footnote, it makes terrible weapon.

Comment: +5 damage against tall grass

Comment: @Miniman I personally suspect spillover from the (original?) fantasy wielders of scythes, who were often literally Death or incarnations/disciples thereof. The deadliness of the wielder has been projected onto deadliness of the weapon.

Answer (score 11):

## RAW, there is no "scythe" available for players.

All weapon options available to players are in the PHB on page 149.

However, there are weapons that are physically somewhat similar to a scythe, namely:

- the *Sickle*, a simple melee weapon with 1d4 damage, which is pretty much a scythe, except much smaller
- and the *Glaive* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaive)), a two-handed martial melee weapon with 1d10 damage and the reach property

You shouldn't have much difficulty convincing your DM to permit you to buy a homebrew scythe with the stats of a glaive.

In fact, unless your DM is really strict, he (or she) will probably allow you to re-flavor any weapon into a scythe. That way, you can, for example, use the longsword stats (1d8 slashing, versatile) for a scythe. Balance-wise, this makes literally no difference whatsoever and merely has an RP-effect, so any DM I know would allow it.

Comment: I agree with the reflavouring comment in general; however, a scythe is almost certainly a two-handed weapon, so if someone is mechanically treating it as one-handed (and doing something else with their other hand), the flavour might be a bit difficult to swallow.  Likewise treating it as a weapon that does bludgeoning damage might be a bit off.  Best to stick with weapons that have scythe-like properties for your reflavouring.

Answer (score 10):

### There is no Scythe weapon RAW

As the other answers have already pointed out, there are currently no stats for a Scythe weapon in any of the official products. It certainly isn't listed on the weapons table in PHB (p. 149).

### A Glaive is a good approximation

The best way to introduce a Scythe that I've found is simply reskinning a Glaive. Other answers have suggested this, but I've actually done this in the past (see below). A Glaive is a heavy, two-handed weapon with 10 ft. reach, like how you would imagine a Scythe would be, and although typically farmers would wield Scythes as makeshift weapons, the martial weapon proficiency represents how unwieldy they would be without the proper training and practice. The d10 slashing damage also seems representative of the Scythe's large blade.

### My players seemed to agree

As DM, I have had two separate players in two separate games ask me about having a Scythe. In both instances I offered them the option of reskinning a Glaive. It worked well for both of them (one was a Paladin, the other a Pact of the Blade Warlock).

The two-handed, heavy and reach properties, as well as the d10 slashing damaging, really made it "feel" like a large Scythe, but RAW, it was a Glaive, so there were no balance concerns whatsoever (for example, no one could use it with a shield, since that's not something the Glaive would allow either). The Paladin character even used it with Polearm Master, since it is actually a Glaive regarding the mechanics, and none of this caused any problems for us.

Answer (score 6):

## No, it isn't

To the best of my knowledge it hasn't been add as an official weapon. You could use roughly the same stats as from 3rd edition, but 5th edition doesn't support the extra critical multiplier from that edition making it less useful.

You could try using similar stats to that of the halberd or glaive.

If you want to try to keep the extra critical multiplier and are willing or able to house rules give it 2d4 damage, heavy and two-handed properties and on a critical hit you roll damage dice 4 times instead of twice.

Comment: Have you done this at your table, or is this a suggestion that hasn't been tested in play yet? The Good Subjective/Bad Subjective guidelines apply.  (Which might answer vlaz' question on where the down votes are coming from).  @vlaz the other answers stick to the glaive mechanics, while this one introduced one that is, or isn't, based on at table experience.

Comment: DD5e also misses the trip property from 3.5. but both this and crit mechanics were changed anyway, so it would be a bad idea to reintroduce then in their old form now